# FabricJs - how to append line to existing line based on the x position of the line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to ask how can I append the new line on the given cords of the x-axis of the existing line (for example Line1 on the attached image).

**Example:** 
I want to append blue lines between **Line1** and **Line3**. I know the only x-position of the blue line on the **Line1** and **Line3**. Y position is unknown, so I need to append start of the blue line on the given x-position on the Line1 and end of the blue line on the given x-position of the Line3.

[image]

Is it possible using FabicJS? And what is the right approach?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If for your Line1 y1=y2 and for your Line3 y1=y2, you will need to take y values for blue lines from Line1 and Line3:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';
var points1 = [ 100, 100, 200, 100 ];
var line1 = new fabric.Line(points1, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
      selectable: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
  });
 var points2 = [ 200, 100, 250, 250 ];
 var line2 = new fabric.Line(points2, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
      selectable: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
  });
 var points3 = [ 250, 250, 50, 250 ];
 var line3 = new fabric.Line(points3, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
      selectable: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
  });
 var points4 = [ 50, 250, 100, 100 ];
 var line4 = new fabric.Line(points4, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
      selectable: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
  });

 var points5 = [ 150, line1.y1, 150, line3.y1 ];
 var line5 = new fabric.Line(points5, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'blue',
      selectable: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
  });
  canvas.add(line1,line2,line3, line4, line5)
```

Fiddle example from above is [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jf1p30dx/60/)

But if your Line1 **y1** not equal to **y2** and for Line3 **y1** not equal **y2**, then you have to calculate **y1** and **y2** values for blue line from  **x-position** of the blue line on the Line1 and Line3.

Your blue line will have logic:

```
var blueX1 = 150;
var blueX2 = 100;
var blueY1 = getY(line1.x1, line1.y1, line1.x2, line1.y2, blueX1);
var blueY2 = getY(line3.x1, line3.y1, line3.x2, line3.y2, blueX2);

 var points5 = [ blueX1, blueY1, blueX2, blueY2 ];
 var line5 = new fabric.Line(points5, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'blue',
      selectable: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
  });


function getY(x1,y1,x2,y2,blueX){
    return (blueX-x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) + y1
  }
```

[Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jf1p30dx/61/) is an updated fiddle. You need to change blueX1 and blueX2 based on your blue intersection with Line1 and Line3